# Get second number from this line of text too

Tags: java, file, text, jtextarea

Currently I can only return 40. 
I want the second number after that too (in this example the 1,600,077.17) 
but not anything after that like the "1,000.00" or the "23" or the "70".
Please keep in mind the String "str" is just an example values sometimes change.

`public static String extractNumber1(final String line) {                
String str = "cows 40 1,600,077.17 1,000.00 23 70"; 

    if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean found = false;
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            sb.append(c);
            found = true;
        } else if(found){
            // If we already found a digit before and this char is not a digit, stop looping
            break;                
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
    }`

Comment: @Ryan Thank you.

Comment: Adding a `regex` tag would attract regex gurus here..

Answer (score 0):

use

```
string[] strAr = str.Split(' ');
```

to convert your string into an array of strings.
`strAr[2]` will be the 1,600,077.17

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string before using spaces. Ex) `String[] strings = str.split(" ")`. Then just check each value in the array for digits. You can then easily pick which values you want to keep.

Comment: This is the one that has worked best,but I found out sometimes amount of spaces change too. Some times it still gets other numbers after the second. Sometimes it gets the second number and returns it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `int found = 0;`

Each time you find a digit, increase found `found++`

change the else if to `if(found==2)`, drop the "else"

full code:

```
public static String extractNumber1(final String line) {                
String str = "cows 40 1,600,077.17 1,000.00 23 70"; 

    if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int found = 0;
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            sb.append(c);
            found++;
        } if(found==2){
            // If we already found a digit before and this char is not a digit, stop looping
            break;                
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
    }
```

edit: drop the else

Answer (score 0):

You can make `found` an `int`, increase it when you find a number and break on `found = 2`.

I would use a different approach though, I would split the string and check if the parts are numbers trying a conversion to double

```
public static String extractNumber1(final String line) {                

    String str = "cows 40 1,600,077.17 1,000.00 23 70"; 

    if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) return "";

    String[] parts = str.split(" ");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int found = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < parts.length && found < 2){
        try {
            long x = Long.parseLong(parts[i]);
            found++;
            sb.append(parts[i]);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        } finally {
            i++; // continue with the loop without breaking
        }
    }  
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the line with a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
String str = "cows 40 1,600,077.17 1,000.00 23 70";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) (\\d+) ([0-9,.]+) ([0-9,.]+) (\\d+) (\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)
        System.out.println(i + ": " + m.group(i));
}
```

*Output*

```
1: cows
2: 40
3: 1,600,077.17
4: 1,000.00
5: 23
6: 70
```

As an example, if you want to get the first two numbers, like the question says, and you want them as actual numbers, not strings, do this inside the `if` statement:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getInstance();
int    firstNumber  = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
double secondNumber = fmt.parse(m.group(3)).doubleValue();
System.out.printf("1st = %d  2nd = %.2f%n", firstNumber, secondNumber);
```

*Output*

```
1st = 40  2nd = 1600077.17
```